# how to move a view controller along a circle in iOS

Tags: ios, view, controller, geometry

I'm new iOS developer. i want to create transition animation between 2 view controller

How can i do ?

here is my code :

```
int newScreenDegrees = _screenDegrees - 90;
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
                  duration:0.65f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^{
                    for(int i = 0; i < [self.screens count]; i++)
                    {
                        UIViewController *_screen = [self.screens objectAtIndex:i];

                        int curDeg = newScreenDegrees + i * SPACE_PER_SCREEN;
                        float curRad = convertDegreesToRadians(curDeg);

                        float newX = COORDINATES_CENTER_OF_CIRCLE_X + (CIRCLE_RADIUS * cos(curRad)) - (_screen.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 280;
                        float newY = COORDINATES_CENTER_OF_CIRCLE_Y + (CIRCLE_RADIUS * sin(curRad)) - (_screen.view.frame.size.height / 2);
                        // transform view
                        _screen.view.transform = transformMakeRotateTranslate(convertDegreesToRadians(curDeg + 90), newX, newY);

                    }
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    _screenDegrees = newScreenDegrees;

                    // TODO: init content of current view and clear other views

                }];
_screenDegrees = newScreenDegrees;
```

**Problems is :** View move along a line not a circle.

Thanks

here is image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVQb3.jpg

Comment: can i move anchor point slowly from btm left to btm right ?. hmm

Answer (score 1):

You need to have multiple loops and move the view individually.  Break the circle your moving along into small enough segments it will look like the view is being moved in a circular fashion.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [self.screens count]; i++)
{                
    UIViewController *_screen = [self.screens objectAtIndex:i];
    int newScreenDegrees = i*90;
    int numSegs=30; //break into little chunks
    int segSize=3;//3 degrees
    for (int m=1;m<=numSegs;m++)
    {
         [UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
              duration:0.65f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
            animations:^{

                    int curDeg = newScreenDegrees+m*segSize;
                    float curRad = convertDegreesToRadians(curDeg);

                    float newX = COORDINATES_CENTER_OF_CIRCLE_X + (CIRCLE_RADIUS * cos(curRad)) - (_screen.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 280;
                    float newY = COORDINATES_CENTER_OF_CIRCLE_Y + (CIRCLE_RADIUS * sin(curRad)) - (_screen.view.frame.size.height / 2);
                    _screen.view.transform = transformMakeRotateTranslate(convertDegreesToRadians(curDeg), newX, newY);


            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                _screenDegrees = newScreenDegrees;

                // TODO: init content of current view and clear other views

            }];
     }
}
```

Comment: sr! but it still wont work for me, i think i will use timer. it's the last case i chose. anyway thanks for answer my question :D